# connect to db instance in private VPC subnet with MySQL Workbench

Tags: linux, mysql, amazon-web-services, subnet, amazon-vpc

How do I connect to an AWS (or other) instance in a private subnet in a VPC using MySQL Workbench ?

My arrangement is a typical aws [Scenario 2](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Scenario2.html) :

I can:
- SSH into my NAT instance located in my VPC public subnet
- SSH from my NAT instance into the db instance in my VPC private subnet
- connect to MySQL as `root` user once connected to my private db instance

What is the correct procedure to set up the system to connect remotely via MySQL workbench ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Connect to db in private subnet instance via NAT with MySQL Workbench

---

**Create a mysql user who can connect remotely:**

- by default the `root` user cannot connect remotely
- create a user who is allowed to connect from your IP address (or use % which means *any* address)
  -- connect to the db instance in the private subnet via SSH
  -- log into mysql as root and type password when prompted:
  `mysql -h localhost -u root -p`
  -- run the following query to create a user
  `CREATE USER 'username'@'XX.XX.XX.XX' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword';`
  -- ensure that the user you've added has all privileges required:
  `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'username'@'IP' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`
- ensure that the users you are adding are not duplicates in either username or password
  -- view the user table in terminal with the following mysql query:
  `select * from mysql.user\G;`
  -- it's a good idea to delete the anonymous user for both security and potential user collisions:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299148
- when complete run query: `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

---

**Set up your security groups to allow remote MySQL connection via the NAT instance:**

- with WorkBench you're SSH tunnelling up to the NAT then connecting via port 3306 to the db instance
- ensure that the IP you're connecting from is allowed to connect to port 3306 in AWS security group
  -- the NAT instance should have SSH(22) *inbound* from your IP address
  -- the NAT instance should have MySQL(3306) *outbound* towards the VPC address range (eg 10.0.0.0/16)
  -- the db instance in the VPC private subnet should allow *inbound* MySQL(3306) from the VPC private IP range (eg 10.0.0.0/16)

---

**Set up Workbench to connect to your db instance via the NAT instance:**

- open WorkBench
- create a new connection and give it a name (eg my_vpc_db1)
  -- choose 'Standard TCP/IP over SSH' as connection method
  -- SSH host is the public IP of the NAT intance e.g. XX.XX.XX.XX
  -- SSH Username = ec2-user
  -- SSH Password is blank (clear this if necessary)
  -- SSH Key File = browse to location of the key_pair.pem file
  -- MySQL Hostname = private IP address of the db instance in the VPC
  -- MySQL Server Port = 3306
  -- username = the name you just added in CREATE USER
  -- password = just added in CREATE USER